# Importing intra-dependent relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My CSV structure is as follows:

```
Origin City   Destination City  Route  Sales
A                     B           XYZ     $5
B                     C           ZED    $50
C                     A           FGH    $15
```

Origin and destination cities are from the same bucket i.e. there should be only 3 nodes in this case (A, B, and C) whereas relationship will have 2 properties: sales and route.

When I use the:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/citylist2.csv' as line fieldterminator ','
MERGE (c:City {id: line.`Origin City`})
MERGE (c)-[r:SALES{id: line.Route, sales: line.Sales}]->(c)
```

code then it creates a self-referencing flower graph. How d I solve this? I need 3 nodes and intra-node relationships with sales and route as properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/citylist2.csv' as line fieldterminator ',' 
MERGE (c1:City {id: line.`Origin City`})
MERGE (c2:City {id: line.`Destination City`})
MERGE (c1)-[r:SALES{id: line.Route, sales: line.Sales}]->(c2);
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom. this works! 
Why did the second line not create another set of city nodes with same labels despite you mentioning c2 (different from c1)?

Comment: As soon as i added another property to MERGE (c1:City {id: line.`Origin City`, state: line.`Origin State`}) it started showing Origin State as labels in the graph. How do I change it back to origin city?

Comment: To your first question, the MERGE will first try to find and only then CREATE. So actually with the first line of input the first MERGE creates 'A', the second MERGE creates 'B' and the third MERGE creates the relationship. With the second line of input the first MERGE finds 'B', the second MERGE creates 'C' and the third MERGE creates the relationship. Und so weiter :-)

Comment: You may actually benefit from having the following constraint : CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City) ASSERT c.id IS UNIQUE;

Comment: As to your second question ... that's just a choice the browser makes. There is a bar which shows the labels in the graph with a count. Select the label you want to change and at the bottom you'll be able to change the colour and the property that is shown as the caption.